# Graph count Prometheus PushGateway API calls

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have Django API and I push custom api_call metric with value 1 to Prometheus PushGateway for each route with all parameters, thus my metric looks like:

```
api_call{ip="45.152.122.130",job="post",password="ffff",route="CustomObtainAuthToken",username="newuser1"}  1
api_call{ip="45.152.122.130",job="post",password="ffff",route="CustomObtainAuthToken",username="newuser2"}  1
api_call{ip="45.152.122.130",job="list",pk="me",route="FUserViewSet",token="Token 35c4535f8570dd127531632f9b72affc471e0afe"}    1
api_call{ip="45.152.122.130",job="retrieve",pk="450",route="UserImageViewSet",token="Token 3deb1b01acc27a624e86e9b14f98de64ada1bf8b"}   1
api_call{ip="45.152.122.130",job="create",route="UserImageViewSet",token="Token 3deb1b01acc27a624e86e9b14f98de64ada1bf8b",url="users/dbc39b1b52be4c7b88324469bfc642df",user="https://newfashion.ehedge.xyz/fusers/880/"}
```

Now I am trying to Graph api_call metric to get total API calls count for every 5 minutes interval or 0 if no calls were made disregarding of params in brackets, graph similar to internal counter: sum(increase(pushgateway_http_requests_total[5m])). I tried rate function - it always returns 0, sum_over_time(api_call[5m]) returns incorrect sum. The only working graph is sum(api_call), which returns continuously increasing correct number of all API calls. My question is how can I get 5 minutes interval increases for such graph (0 if values does not change), for my metric with value 1 and many different params?

Answer (score 1):

Finally used sum(api_call) -  sum(api_call offset 5m) to graph counts of all API calls in every 5 minutes interval